# Fastest way to find an element in database

Tags: database, search

I am not sure if this is an appropriate question for this site. But I didn't find any place to ask such question .

Once in an interview I was asked that, there are more than 2 million products in a database for an apparel store, those products has no tag , no category or anything else, just product name . How can I search an product in that database in most efficient way ?

I answered Linear Search . But the interviewer wasn't satisfied.

Comment: Fire the interviewer for the question.

Comment: @FDavidov lol , I wish I could do that

Comment: That sounds like a stupid question. With a database given, you simply write an appropriate query, e.g. `select * from product where name = :name`. It's the DBMS's task to search in the most efficient way, not yours. This is what a DBMS is all about. Well, maybe this is the answer the interviewer wanted to hear.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Maybe they wanted to hear that but I was confused as it was a position for software engineer specially on Java and android .

Comment: Then maybe they wanted to hear "select this one record from the database" as opposed to "read all records, fill an array, search the array". Sometimes it's hard to guess what answer an interviewer has in mind ;-)

Answer (score 0):

hashtables
just create the hash function which would convert a name of an item in a database to a number and then just find the element by its index

```
function hash(name){
    /*convert a name into a number eg by converting each letter into a corresponding ascii number and multiplying it by a random number(to avoid collisions however there are many more efficient ways to avoid collisions and reducing memory requirements*/
    return name //which will be hashed
}

database[hash(name)]
```